# Spring boot with profiles: javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have application.properties in resource dir

```
server.port = 8888
```

Pool bean

```
@Bean
@Profile("local")
protected DataSource dataSource(@Value("${db.driver}") String driver,...) {
    HikariConfig configuration = new HikariConfig();//........
    return new HikariDataSource(configuration);
}
```

Config

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Skipped other my configs, because all works without profile annotation.

App runs with

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Is the `protected` intended?

Comment: Thx!!!! Protected is a kind of typo here.

Comment: what do you want to fix?

Answer (score 1):

based on information provided, you its not able to create the DataSource bean for which 'db.driver' value is required. This property needs to be mentioned in application properties. Try adding this property in propertySource. 
or you provide some default value for this property, something like this:

```
@Value("${db.driver:'defaultValue'}"
```

if error still exists, pls add stack trace and code-snippet for info to determine whats going on.